# Differential Equation of volume and area of raindrop

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this pretty long question about differential equations in my homework list:

> In very dry regions, the phenomenon called Virga is very important
>   because it can endanger aeroplanes. [See
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virga ]. Virga is rain in air that is so
>   dry that the raindrops evaporate before they can reach the ground.
>   Suppose that the volume of a raindrop is proportional to the 3/2 power
>   of its surface area. [Why is this reasonable? Note: raindrops are not
>   spherical, but let’s assume that they always have the same shape, no
>   matter what their size may be.] Suppose that the rate of reduction of
>   the volume of a raindrop is proportional to its surface area. [Why is
>   this reasonable?] Find a formula for the amount of time it takes for a
>   virga raindrop to evaporate completely, expressed in terms of the
>   constants you introduced and the initial surface area of a raindrop.
>   Check that the units of your formula are correct. Suppose somebody
>   suggests that the rate of reduction of the volume of a raindrop is
>   proportional to the square of the surface area. Argue that this cannot
>   be correct.

I tried doing the following:

\begin{align}
  \text{Let V(t) = Volume of rain drop, A(t) = Surface Area of rain drop }
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  \frac{dV}{dt} = -k(A(t))^{3/2} \text{ where k > 0}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  dV = -k(A(t))^{3/2} \, \mathrm dt
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \text{Integrating, we get:}& \\ \\
  V = -kt(A(t))^{3/2} &+ c \text{ where } c = A_0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  \therefore V = -kt(A(t))^{3/2} &+ A_0
\end{align}

I am not sure how to carry on from here. Could anyone please advise me?

Comment: Hint: Is $A(t)$ constant? Did you integrate the expression correctly? Also, you have not used all the information given in the question. Taking the hint further: Try expressing volume in terms of area, and $\mathrm dV/\mathrm dt$ in terms of volume.